# Symfony3 authentication with Ldap and Oauth2 server

Tags: symfony, authentication, oauth-2.0, ldap, symfony-3.1

I need to create an application that fetches User from Ldap and then, generates a token for him to access Restful interface.

First, I am using [LdapToolsBundle](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle) and I could login using Ldap and login form easily.

Then, I am studying [FosOauthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) and [oauth2-server-bundle](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-bundle) and trying to figure out which one is better for my application. I've installed FosOauthServerBundle correctly but didn't find a way to integrate with LdapToolsBundle.

I studied the possibility of using Fr3dLdapBundle and if anyone has the solution using this bundle, I would be open up.

The problem:
I don't need to persist User Entity. But, if it is required, I don't want to persist it's password. I need always the password being checked from Ldap on every token authentication.

Could anyone help me? I would be greatful.